# when I'm try to build react project then show this error

Tags: css, reactjs, server, build, project

[enter image description here][1][build error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4Nmc.png)

when I'm try to build react project then show this error. please help me

Answer (score -1):

I think enough info is not provided in attached screenshot but you can look into the css files imports in components or may be you can try disabling some fancy CSS rules if you have used anywhere i.e.

```
mask-image: linear-gradient(to bottam, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
```